# ListView DynamicResource

Tags: wpf, vb.net, .net-3.5, dynamicresource

When attempting to use a DynamicResource as an ItemsSource for a ListView my application is outputting the error:

> Window must be the root of the tree.
>   Cannot add Window as a child of
>   Visual.

If I was to remove the ItemsSource, and leave the code alone, then I dont get the error and an empty ListView will display.

My ListView located in my Window.XAML is as follows:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" Grid.RowSpan="4" ItemsSource="{DynamicResource tasksResponsibilitiesCollection}">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
                                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding tasksResponsibilitiesName}" Header="Tasks/Responsibility" Width="150" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Member Responsible" Width="120" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Qualifications" Width="110" />
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
```

The ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection defined in the code-behind.  I have been using the MSDN example (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747048.aspx) as my guide for the creation of the ListView

How do I go about bidning the ObservableCollection to the ListView?  Do I have to define the resource within Window.XAML somewhere?

If there is anything that I haven't covered please let me know.

I appreciate your assistance,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `ObservableCollection` is defined as a property in the code-behind of the window then you could use data binding to set `ItemsSource`, like this:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" Grid.RowSpan="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=tasksResponsibilitiesCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding tasksResponsibilitiesName}" Header="Tasks/Responsibility" Width="150" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Member Responsible" Width="120" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Qualifications" Width="110" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Please note that `tasksResponsibilitiesCollection` must be a public property in you window code-behind.